# insert statement mysql adding nulls

Tags: python, mysql, database, timestamp

I have a script in python which is inserting data into an MYSQL database. Problem is its adding nulls for some reason. Here is the code.

```
    #Drop previous table of same name if one exists
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArduinoData;")
print("Finished dropping table (if existed).")
# Create table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE ArduinoData (value VARCHAR(40),myTimeStamp TIMESTAMP);")
print("Finished creating table.")

# Insert some data into table
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ArduinoData (value) VALUES (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s);",[arduinoData])
print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ArduinoData (myTimeStamp) VALUES (now())")
print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
```

The data that is going into the value column is just five strings. when I run this file, this happens.

[Nulls being added picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIkSy.jpg)

I have tried adding not null after creation of the columns but nothing seems to be working, any ideas?

Comment: when inserting a row, all columns that are left out from the insert will be "null". Are you trying to do this: ("INSERT INTO ArduinoData (value, myTimeStamp) VALUES (%s, now())") ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite sure I understand, why is it adding a null to the last value of the arduino data then because I've written it so only 5 values are added to it and only 1 adding to the myTimeStamp column

Comment: you are inserting 5 rows with only the value column populated, so the timestamp for those 5 rows will be null. Then you are adding a new row with only the timestap populated the the value column will be null for that new row.

Comment: So I should insert it all in one statement then really

Comment: yes like i asked in a previous comment.

Comment: BTW, if you want to populate a column from an existing row, you need to use UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Comment: Okay thanks, I only want to insert a timestamp when a certain condition is met so I guess I can't insert them all in one go, yeah the update statement might work